# Differential to single-ended converter (ARINC 429)

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, instrumentation-amplifier

I'm trying to design a circuit to take a [ARINC 429](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARINC_429) signal and convert it into a signal that can be read by a microcontroller. This will not be airborne and is just to interface a real radio with a flight sim. The ARINC signal is a differential pair ±5 V (10 V p-p). I need a 0-5 V digital signal to be read by the microcontroller.

Looking into differential amplifiers, they seem to generate a +/- signal where I need positive only. Additionally I'm thinking a clock signal to verify the data too?

[image: Circuit]

I've had a go on Falstad to design a circuit [(link)](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEBmWAWAbAdgwDgxmAEwJGQJogKRUhrJUCmAtGGAFADuIzAnMeBw9cYDILGQuPfkXADmIsW1mSAztKFghfAVolQQAMwCGAG1WN26vpvky5KgyfOWASjzbIxzDJVZgvaX0aNBokGgjoBHZ3ViI0XB5fD3jEvmC6GmZwgxho7jiEpL9iIoipf0CfEoDgit5NbVLEvSgK5pRZQpahSTAEXhSi5C6OiJAycHhp%20HZ%20wcqxEY9a3ImaMBmZ9tXlxYc2guJl0RXJ08kj4g3vTfjwCSsPSHvT9JuDCGcLHark9%20KhyCWX%20vAwHzUz3uoPBIGSGyMZh%20BQaSiaq1al2BD2x8LmAxWuEoYMJlHh6ymW1mR1SBn8RNyOwZWTYDLxV0Cyg0SgEWPpxNuYAZXL5rMoXP2Ip2eBAuBZL0ocqBrAVcJKqqVfLBNBhGyIiS1sOIaU8Sn1bXmK056M5aEoNHOVOpVrNJoxduVd0V8tesNFqtELOuD3KAHMkggxPEQZGJlhHJIAE4RtHeDCx6MGNBYZ3MLDWtOxzEVfM8rrpsvK%20iyJXMavgD1JngkMS1%20ua8DUOAVetgXhdIivftVk4eusnYdYklkFqwmdAknJQNqoHLefTyAGqTLZKL%203sZMksAejcGug57uHpQnsTk7OzcNHj1LxttAAmPCK87Xm4mIDfjAmAArqYAAu7AfnWiTJDulCyABwFge05r-EUeLJlBDZ%20Gh9oTGQTaYce2GJPODr4chJG-phpExJ%20LRjkqRFrKEtDjHktHMIOlBFJxsZlFmNCoAwbFRAePBeIkyCQH4LYoNJnxdpIsQSXJ2FwKpzFZEJazsTSlEmuaUn7gUslcc2sZGcqZlmbxUb3ARsmWXEknyRsWwUSuzngOaDlFuaXnGp87kmbGtayYFfJmWFoXlAU4IkbGnG4AljwmclBxJSlnq2AO6VSkcQgkqwOXZVGLHFVGsZ8vFEyJa0sl8iM4zME1WHKjVWmTLFHiaGOrVMaKjS3L1xk9foFWdO1v4sr0bShAs1lUYF84QDA3gwMgvCRiQFDUMgmzIMlEiwEQ%201zZAC3QiUKHilA0DrdAm3bRQvD3gMCCbXdLxnXykYbGOvaNhUHVJL%20UqxCD1RsQJrG5KJcVg9oNUNRxyOJb4DpVTD2Q6fDPB-XQaQEwNwN8UTsJlGJPhFvIFaE1mF7VUWsLU6m7U0%20WflbvNKZtdkRoeqt92ftA82QIdyCRjmyCHQaJ0-RUijiDwpbK3ySsSqrUr9LIy7LXlPl-mEUjLkuRq8ibAvinO01SPqLSGaQ3lbgAHnJuvHigGAe1gdATJQADCpgAPYAMYANaWzqlCS7IeJu0Qr10IMyAek7cGUAAIsYoHGOwbsqlgSAQCqRBiNx-sgAAEgAlqGAAW%20fPLgSDe88aAQOmfv3AAMsHnDsMH4A4iEF2JOE0CrX7EDCWsyCD3Q1sCbw493RAEDcTHIArwYO-z0AA)
bet it seems over complicated (with 2 +/- rails) and the clock generation seems too simple (just an or gate). Any help would be much appreciated.

- Red: Clock
- Green : Data

Or am I over-complicating this and would something like just an OR gate and a diode suffice?

[Second circuit:](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAXKQUgoFMBaMMAKDXKcgxREIBYQnPrX4gBAGQD2AdzZdBYLj1pDatAQAkAlgHMAFiwDOgsoXDEeDYmB5gLUBwDMAhgBtDdIyYxmbeEzbgKP5qIC7ungBKCmDYZgx8-kyx8Xih6rRI6dAILNFMKImCRQUlaQ4ZglkVOSzSCoVJJTZFYGaQdTFxxUnM3W1QnVY%205pYt-nbKQ%20NivY2jg2AIxA1FzfMDtGjI8LtwLEsryd3NKeDtINuKe7vTZ6f9wYP1Bdg8bzHbHx0vzF9jkEKIG%20Xk4QI%20VkItG%204DCbg8d26CSSxChPWeJjRyMx0KmxjBAnKkNo5VoEHCCJepgWx189h%20OOBllRJLUB2WMTwAj%20nMJoSuN1uvw28WYXPOGOS4oGUr5kr6view0VITu0sCsqCqt%20YGlSoVWvlbX8qIUgIEpoZBJARMUQMtQxZNpUTrAfAEVtd7q6vm9HUOPppBra-LJgvgiN9Alp5zZv3NIFN1rAIytdu5I2SV1TjsCfkEeAG%20c9efsDELdKmS0sFfAmZwvlTlwcuRetfz5aLaI6ABMC0WlQ3DTwe3QXABXVwAFxYACdBEOO0PROoMBGdAvuqIGEOYVbF0rCEDi0NF5mjxn2nIOBfDQxKCqxCAACLOKfOa%20CW8p%20IPutmAQAGFXEkABjABrFhJDEJAVzESBiH8LJoAgLYYOBKCxAEODhEQigoBQ2EeG9bAWCAA)

[image: simple]

Comment: Isn't ARINC 429 trilevel signalling? I don't see that in your simulation.

Comment: There is only an A&B Lines that are either +5/-5 (HIGH), -5/+5(LOW) or both 0v (NULL).

Comment: What should the output be for each of these states?

Comment: +5/-5 (HIGH) -> Clock & DATA HIGH,
-5/+5 (LOW) -> Clock HIGH, DATA LOW
0/0 -> CLOCK and DATA LOW

Comment: And what are the thresholds for each situation?

Comment: As long as the digital voltages are above the Logical high level then it should be fine. On most microcontrollers its about 2.6 volts. A think 3v would be a minimum. In an ideal world the output would be 0-5v levels.

Comment: No the input thresholds, what should they be to decide +/0/-?

Comment: Not sure. 3v as a conservative HIGH threshold. Measured on the scope it was -5/0/+5

Comment: This: http://www.helitavia.com/avionics/TheAvionicsHandbook_Cap_2.pdf suggests a (+/-)3-6V threshold would be adequate, but preferably one would look up the direct standard, or reference implementations thereof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two comparators do the trick. LM393 would be a single-chip receiver solution, then - plus a few resistors.

The common mode is in excess of ±100V relative to receiver ground. The differential input resistance is 100kΩ. Should be plenty for lab use.

The GND of the receiver should be connected to the shield or to the frame. No differential amps needed - comparators are already differential, all that's needed is to set up some reference voltages for them :)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEnvFo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R3,R6,R7,R10 must be 0.5% or better tolerance. The rest can be 1% or 5% tolerance. R1-R10 should be metal film. The small comparator offset is of no consequence in this circuit.

R1,R2 should be 0.5W or 1W to accommodate the full common mode range.

The comparators can be the basic general-purpose LM393, LM339, LM2901, etc. They're just about sufficient for this application. A slightly faster comparator could be used as well, but most likely is not necessary.

The cost for the whole thing is something silly like $5 in parts qty 1 :)

The differential input-to-output transfer function:

[image: The differential input-to-output transfer function]

The input signal (top), HIGH and LOW outputs, and the CLK output:

[image: Input and output signal waveforms]

Caveat: This circuit is fine for lab use to receive data, but is not anywhere near what would be needed in a piece of avionics, and is not usable as-is in assessing compliance of transmitters etc.

Adding a bit of hysteresis to the comparators wouldn't hurt. That's the exercise for the reader - there's already a circuit with all the simulations set up :)

The extra gate in the clock recovery circuit is used to ensure that the hold times of most any latch or shift register are upheld. The OR gates could be CD4071 - then you'd only need the first one, since they are slow enough at 5V. Otherwise, two or four 74HC32 in series would do the trick.

There may need to be speed-up capacitors in parallel to both R1 and R2. It would need to be a small value - a couple pF at most, and once a value is determined the second capacitor should be selected to be within 2-5% of the value of the first one. Whether this is necessary would be determined with an oscilloscope, observing the input-to-output  delay, which should be <2μs.

For best AC performance, the circuit should be laid out symmetrically so that the parasitic impedances are balanced for each leg of the input.

Answer (score 1):

The receiver for deserialization is conceptually simple but there are a lot of nuances that are difficult to get right if you aren’t intimately familiar with the application and the myriad practical issues. For example, how much baseline wander is expected and can your design tolerate that?

If you want to make a circuit work, I’d recommend starting by prototyping with a line receiver designed for ARINC 429. Look at the Holt HI-8588 as an example. If you want to work on a discrete solution, that’s certainly a cool project, but note that there’s a bit of depth to solving this problem robustly. If I wanted to do a discrete solution, I’d probably wire up an integrated part as a comparative tool anyway.

Edit: I should note that you can do clock recovery with an OR function across the line receiver outputs.

Comment: The HI Chips are difficult to source and expensive. This is just a hobby project to try and get a real aircraft radio working with a flight sim.

Comment: @GeorgeGohl That detail is sort of important and really belongs in the question. Feel free to edit the question to add it there - that'll definitely improve it, as without such detail the question is somewhat open-ended.

Comment: Ah, if you're looking more for something to learn and play with, as opposed to a reliably piece of avionics equipment, then that changes things for sure! The other answer looks like a great starting point. But as he mentions, you wouldn't want to assume it's a robust solution.